# Finding two bases for a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am finding two bases for S=<$\left( \begin{array}{c}
1\\ 
1\\
0\\
1\\
1\end{array}\right)$,$\left( \begin{array}{c}
2\\ 
0\\
1\\
1\\
2\end{array}\right)$, $\left( \begin{array}{c}
5\\ 
3\\
1\\
4\\
5\end{array}\right)$, $\left( \begin{array}{c}
-1\\ 
0\\
-1\\
0\\
-1\end{array}\right)$> in $\mathbb R^5$

I created a matrix based off of a system of equations and found one basis to be: $ \left( \begin{array}{c}
1\\ 
1\\
0\\
1\\
1\end{array}\right)$,$\left( \begin{array}{c}
2\\ 
0\\
1\\
1\\
2\end{array}\right)$, $\left( \begin{array}{c}
-1\\ 
0\\
-1\\
0\\
-1\end{array}\right)$

I'm not sure how to find another basis. I tried to find one using rows instead of columns but those won't be in $\mathbb R^5$

Comment: Any 3 linearly independent column vectors in S can make a basis.

Comment: Use Gram-Schmidt

Comment: I have not been taught Gram-Schmidt @Felix.C

Answer (score 1):

The first basis you've found tells you that any other basis consists of three independent vectors in $S$. To get another basis you could use the vector you left out of the first one and combine it linearly with the other ones to get some more independent vectors that you haven't used yet.
For example, let $v_1=\begin{pmatrix}5\\3\\1\\4\\5\end{pmatrix}$, $v_2=\begin{pmatrix}5\\3\\1\\4\\5\end{pmatrix}-2\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\1\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\\-1\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}$, and $v_3=\begin{pmatrix}5\\3\\1\\4\\5\end{pmatrix}-3\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\0\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}$.

$\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is also a basis of $S$ because of the linear independence of the vectors you chose for the first basis.

Alternatively, you could apply the Gram-Shmidt algorithm.

Comment: In this example wouldn't  {$\vec v_1, \vec v_2, \vec v_3$}be linear combinations of one another, thus making them linearly dependent? And I thought bases needed to be linearly independent.

Comment: No, they are not. There would be linear dependence if $v_1=\alpha v_2+\beta v_3$ for some $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$, which is not the case. I did construct the vectors using linear combinations of the vectors you provided, but I did not put $\textit{those}$ vectors I've used into the basis.

Comment: Alright I understand. Thank you for clearing that up. Also, would do you believe setting the matrix up with the vectors as rows instead of columns and then using our echelon form matrix would work as well?

Comment: Yes, it would work. You would have to reduce the matrix to the echelon form and then choose linearly independent vectors by looking at pivots in the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Or replace first or second basis vector as found, by the third in the list. Note that the third vector is 3 times first plus second.